# How to delete an annotated tag (git tag) in VSTS API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm able to successfully create an annotated tag (git tag) with the request below, but I'm not able to programmatically delete it.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/annotatedtags?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

Request:

```
{
    "name": "wagner-test-3",
    "message": "wagner-test-3",
    "taggedObject": {
        "objectId": "aaaaab6cad84a07b7bd65cf3519142a12f856baa"
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/annotated%20tags?view=vsts-rest-4.1) there is no delete endpoint, so I've tried the [delete ref endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/refs/delete?view=vsts-rest-4.1) but no luck so far.  It only returns 400 (Invalid Request).

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/favorites/refs/{favoriteId}?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

Response:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": {
        "Message": "The request is invalid."
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to figure out my own question. The way to delete an annotated tag is to update it with the Refs API.  This is not well documented though.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=4.1
```

Request:

```
[
    {
        "name": "refs/tags/wagner-test-3",
        "newObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "oldObjectId": "aaaaab6cad84a07b7bd65cf3519142a12f856baa"
    }
]
```

**Azure DevOps documentation:**
[Refs - Update Refs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/refs/update%20refs?view=vsts-rest-4.1)
Creating, updating, or **deleting** refs(branches).